# How to specify in razor pdf landscape orientation in .cshtml

Tags: pdf, razor, itext, landscape

I`m using RazorPDF from the NuGet Package and i want to know how i can set the page to render as landscape.

The code of the page is something like this:

```xml
<itext pagesize="A4">
..... some content .....
</itext>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this attribute

```
orientation="landscape"
```